# Can't get jQuery datepicker tr class to work

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

I think I'm missing something simple here but I can't seem to get the tr selector to work in a datepicker I'm building. I'd just like to apply a simple border to the table rows so the calendar displays like a grid but can't seem to get it to play ball.

Any ideas?? Here's a copy of the datepicker:

http://jsfiddle.net/oakass/6tbqw8px/

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="from" placeholder="From">
<input type="text" id="to" placeholder="To">
```

jQuery

```
(function ($) {
$(function () {

    $("#from").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        firstDay: 1,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });


    $("#to").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        firstDay: 1,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });

});

})(jQuery);
```

CSS

```
        .ui-datepicker {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    font: 9pt'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.ui-datepicker a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.ui-datepicker table {
    width: 100%;
}

.ui-datepicker-header {
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.ui-datepicker-title {
    text-align: center;
}

a.ui-datepicker-next:after {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content:"\f054";
    margin-right: 20px;
}

a.ui-datepicker-prev:before {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content:"\f053";
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.ui-datepicker-prev {
    float: left;
    background-position: center -30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-datepicker-next {
    float: right;
    background-position: center 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-icon-circle-triangle-e, .ui-icon-circle-triangle-w {
  display: none;
}

.ui-datepicker th {
    color: #333333;
}

.ui-datepicker td span, .ui-datepicker td a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #333333;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-hover {
    background: #9e2316;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Oli

Comment: i think you missed jQuery UI CSS [file](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css) or didn't copy all required styles of datepicker from css file.  [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf83agzf/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the table `border-collapse:collapse`.

Now the border should be showing when added on `tr`.

**[example](http://jsfiddle.net/6tbqw8px/1/).**